# LinkedIn share returns cached URL when sending to a specific person Issue

Tags: linkedin-api

Lately i've been working on a share button which should take some specific information on the website and post it on LinkedIn. The website is an single-page application with Angular ui-router.

I followed LinkedIns developer guide docs with the customized URL to execute this action. My link looks like this:

> https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&summary= Description
>   &title= Title &url= Url &picture= Image.

Description, Title, Url and Image are unique values which is set by the content of the page and i've set the Open Graph meta tags:

> meta property="og:title" content="website title"
>   meta property="og:description"
>   content="website description"
>   meta property="og:url" content="website url"
>
> meta property="og:image" content="website image"

Since the page is an single-page application, the page "never" really reloads, but just changes the content inside the body element. Therefore i've created some Javascript to do the job for me which works like a charm with LinkedIn sharing to your network **but *"sending to a specific person"* is inserting the wrong url.**

When the user enter our website, locate to an article they want to share and click on the LinkedIn icon in the top right corner, a new tab appears. In the new tab, the user sees the title of the page, some of the url link and some of the description. They can check whether to share an update or / and send to a specific person. If the user checks to share an update with their network, the correct information is set with title, description, image and url. But when the user wants to send it to a specific person, which the user is notified about in their messages, the title and description is correct, but the link is not.

This issue seems to be connected to some sort of caching. If the user visit a new page, where no one has shared any article or so on linkedIn via the website, the correct link for both the network and the person, who is recieving the message. Let's say it is **website.com/#3/5521**. But when another user wants to share a different article on the page, the message url link is set to the first one, that the other user earlier shared. The link should have been **website.com/#3/9978** but is set to **website.com/#3/5521** no matter what i do. It's the same link that sharing with your network gets as when sharing to a specific person, so i can't see, how i can deal with this problem properly.

I hope this gives an idea of what the issue is. Tell me if you guys need any more explaining.

The problem appears on this website, if you want to see it in live action:
http://gentofte.viewer.dkplan.niras.dk/plan/52#/23703

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not experiencing this problem at all.  Is it still broken?

Here I am trying to share this URL: `http://www.revoltlib.com/?id=17`.  I am using this URL...

```
https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.revoltlib.com%2F%3Fid%3D17
```

This is the screen on sharing...

[image]

And this is the result after sharing...

[image]

It appears to work!  Is it still broken for you?